# is it possible to have multiple search condition in filter function in MDX

Tags: filter, ssas, mdx

Can there be multiple search conditions in the "filter function" in mdx.

If possible how do I put

[Measures].[x] > 0   and [Measures].[y]  = 0

in
filter(set expression, search condition)

Answer (score 2):

yes, I found that it can be added. I dont know what I tried earlier and it didnt work.

the filter function looks like this

filter(set expression, [Measures.[x] > 0 and Measures.[y] = 0)